# API query with user input

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I have a form where user types in the city name, I want to make an API call and get weather results in that city and then display it in the console.

I'm getting an error because for some reason the variable that holds input.value is not being concatenated into the string.

Here's the code:

```js
var request;
var input1 = document.getElementById('city');
var api = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
var apikey = '&APPID=433b12b793d7ebc17989745c069a540b';
var sum = api + input1.value + apikey;

function myFunction() {

  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', sum, true);
  request.onload = function() {

    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      console.log(input1.value);
    }
  }

  request.send();
}
myFunction(input1.value);
```

```html
<input id='city' value='San Francisco'>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Those variable initializations should be *inside* the function. As it is, they'll just run once when the page first loads.

Comment: If you log `input1.value` the correct value shows up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, you just need to put everything inside the function.

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {

        var request;
        var input1 = document.getElementById('city');
        var api = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
        var apikey =
            '&APPID=433b12b793d7ebc17989745c069a540b';
        var sum = api + input1.value + apikey;

        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', sum, true);
        request.onload = function () {

            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                console.log(input1.value);
            }
        }

        request.send();
    }
</script>
```